# PHP - Install mcrypt for PHP 7.2 and API Version 20170718

Tags: php, mcrypt, pecl

I need to install mcrypt for php on my Linux server. I have PECL, and PHP 7.2 running on API version 20170718 (i.e., all the PHP *.so extensions are loaded from /usr/bin/php/20170718). But, when I run,

```
pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

It says,

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20180731
Zend Module Api No:      20180731
Zend Extension Api No:   320180731
libmcrypt prefix? [autodetect] : ...
```

And if I install it, the wrong version gets installed, and it doesn't appear because I'm running php API version 20170717, *not* 20180731. In addition, including it directly from the /usr/bin/php/20180731 directory still causes it to crash since it recognizes it's the wrong API version.

How can I install the proper mcrypt version for PHP API version 20170718?

Comment: The mcrypt extension is deprecated as of 7.1

Comment: _"This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 7.1.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.2.0."_

Comment: That said, you _can_ get mcrypt running under 7.2, but you really shouldn't. It hasn't been actively developed since 2003 and there are much better options, like [Sodium](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php).

Comment: It was *removed* in 7.2? But if 20170718 loosely correlates to PHP 7.2 and 20180731 to PHP 7.3, why is it when I install mcrypt does it appear in the *later* 20180731? Wouldn't it appear in an even older directory?

Comment: Would https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat be suitable for your needs?